# Moving functionality from functions.php to classes?

Tags: theme-development

The `functions.php` file in the theme I’m working on is becoming too big and hard to manage so I’m thinking about moving some functionality to classes. Is it a bad idea?

Not sure how to do it though: do I need to make them singletons? Do I just call new MyClass in functions.php? What are the best practices for splitting functionality (currently I do it be section, e.g. header functions, content functions, etc.)

Comment: the first step to try is to split this file in several files which are included in functions.php

Comment: @mmm this is already done. Those several files are also becoming to big though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code https://github.com/chriscoyier/css-tricks-functionality-plugin does exactly what you've described with regard to classes.  Although the associated article https://css-tricks.com/wordpress-functionality-plugins/ is about removing non-theme specific functionality out of functions.php to a separate plugin it will give you an insight into the code.

HOWEVER:

PHP includes do have a performance overhead. I have also read (older versions of PHP) that classes add a performance overhead, although I beleive this is not the case with PHP 7.

I am unsure whether you are i. modifying a theme for use on your site, or ii.developing a new Theme.

**If just for your site**. I improve maintainability and reduce the size of my child functions.php by limiting it to theme specific functions only; other site functionality is contained in a separate plugin as explained in article above (but just the one file not lots of classes and includes). This file is also very large; but I've also commented in an index at the start and prominent section headings and do not have a problem maintaining it.

**If you are developing and publishing new theme**: bear in mind many users who are happy to use/modify functions do not have the same confidence with object oriented stuff and it may put them off using/childing your theme. Additionally, if they're like me, I find it much easier and less irritating to refer to one large properly commented and sectioned file than have to use functions.php as a look up index to see what other files I need then go away and open to copy, edit or extend.

Comment: I definitely agree on moving non-theme functionality to plugin. As for functions I understand your point, but I can’t find the way to section `functions.php` it properly as it appears there are too many levels and just too many lines.